# VueJs is not render when App.vue import a template from JS file

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have 2 vue files and 1 js files. The App.vue file import both vue and js file. When I clicked on the Help link, it did not render except About. Why the is no output when clicked on Help menu but there is output on About menu .What else I am missing ?

**App.vue file**

```
<script>
import Home from './Home.vue'
import About from './About.vue'
import Help from './Help.js'

const routes = {
  '/': Home,
  '/about': About,
  '/help': Help,
}

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentPath: window.location.hash
    }
  },
  computed: {
    currentView() {
      return routes[this.currentPath.slice(1) || '/'] || NotFound
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
          this.currentPath = window.location.hash
        })
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <a href="#/">Home</a> |
  <a href="#/about">About</a> |
  <a href="#/help">Help</a> |
  <component :is="currentView" />
</template>
```

**Help.js Files**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  mounted (){
    alert(window.location.hash);
  },
  template: `
    <button @click="count++">
      You clicked me {{ count }} times.
    </button>`
}
```

**About.js file**

```
<template>
  <h1>About</h1>
  <button>Click About</button>
</template>
```